# Why has my comment flag request been declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments

A new user asked an off-topic question twice and one of our mod closed both the question as off-topic. But the user was not satisfied with the reason for closing his question and posted an useless comment in an offensive manner. So I flagged that comment as rude/offensive. But my request has been declined. I'm not justifying that I was correct but I need the reason so that I won't flag  such comments in future. Important point is that particular user has been suspended by that mod because of his activity.

Screen shot of the comment:

[image]

Screen shot of declined status:

[image]

Comment: As Stephen indicated, declined flags are only seen by moderators, who understand there are limitations in the system, and can also see the majority of (very) helpful flags as in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had already suspended the user.   My only options were to delete the comment or dismiss the flag.   I didn't think the comment was so bad that I needed to delete it, so I dismissed it.

The flag was helpful, but for comments there doesn't seem to be a way of dismissing the flag *and* marking it as helpful.

"Unhelpful" flags don't count against you in any way.

Comment: I've been in that bind before too. There really ought to be an option for marking comment flags as helpful even if no further action is needed.